# Question on the local existence theory for the classical solution for the incompressible fluid dynamics equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, regularity-theory-of-pdes

For the incompressible fluid dynamics system
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\nabla\cdot v=0,\\
&\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t}+v\cdot \nabla v+\nabla p=A(S,D)v,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $S=\dfrac{\nabla v+\nabla v^T}{2}$ is the deformation rate tensor. The second-order differential operator $A(S,D)=[A_{ij}(S,D)]_{d\times d}$ is defined as follows with $d=2 \text{ or } 3$, and $A(S,D)$ is a strongly elliptic operator.
$$
A_{ij}(S,D)\equiv \sum\limits_{l,k=1}^da_{ij}^{kl}(S)\partial_k\partial_l.
$$
Actually, the incompressible Navier-Stokes system can be obtained by taking $a_{ij}^{kl}=\mu_0\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}$ and $\mu_0$ is the Newtonian viscosity coefficient.

I want to investigate the Cauchy problem of the above system and seeking the local existence of its classical solution in $C([0,T_0],H^s)\cap C'([0,T_0],H^{s-2})$ for some positive constant $T_0$ with $s>d/2+2$ to be an integer.

I am able to manage the compressible case with the estimate in Sobolev space, however I have no idea in how to do it in the incompressible case. Could anyone help me figuring out how to prove the theorem? Or should I alter my existence theorem?

The long time blow-up or regularity of the solution is difficult for this system. Could anyone give some suggestions on the some results for the long-time behavior of the system I considered?

Thanks!

Comment: You should really post this here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/